# jQuery autocomplete not always working on elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, jquery-ui

I'm trying to create a greasemonkey script (for Opera) to add autocomplete to input elements found on a webpage but it's not completely working.

I first got the autocomplete plugin working:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name           autocomplete
// @description    autocomplete
// @include        *
// ==/UserScript==

// Add jQuery
var GM_JQ = document.createElement('script');
GM_JQ.src = 'http://jquery.com/src/jquery-latest.js';
GM_JQ.type = 'text/javascript';
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(GM_JQ);

var GM_CSS = document.createElement('link');
GM_CSS.rel = 'stylesheet';
GM_CSS.href = 'http://dev.jquery.com/view/trunk/plugins/autocomplete/jquery.autocomplete.css';
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(GM_CSS);

var GM_JQ_autocomplete = document.createElement('script');
GM_JQ_autocomplete.type = 'text/javascript';
GM_JQ_autocomplete.src = 'http://dev.jquery.com/view/trunk/plugins/autocomplete/jquery.autocomplete.js';
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(GM_JQ_autocomplete);

// Check if jQuery's loaded
function GM_wait() 
{
    if(typeof window.jQuery == 'undefined') 
    { 
        window.setTimeout(GM_wait,100); 
    }
    else 
    { 
        $ = window.jQuery; 

        letsJQuery(); 
    }
}
GM_wait();

function letsJQuery() 
{
    $("input[type='text']").each(function(index)
    {
        $(this).val("test autocomplete");
    });

    $("input[type='text']").autocomplete("http://mysite/jquery_autocomplete.php", {
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        parse: function(data) {
            var rows = new Array();
            for(var i=0; i<data.length; i++){
                rows[i] = { 
                    data:data[i], 
                    value:data[i], 
                    result:data[i] };
            }
            return rows;
        },
        formatItem: function(row, position, length) {
            return row;
        },
    });
}
```

I see the 'test autocomplete' but using the Opera debugger(firefly) I don't see any communication to my php page. (yes mysite is fictional, but it works here)
Trying it on my own page:

```
<body>
no autocomplete: <input type="text" name="q1" id="script_1"><br>
autocomplete on: <input type="text" name="q2" id="script_2" autocomplete="on"><br>
autocomplete off: <input type="text" name="q3" id="script_3" autocomplete="off"><br>
autocomplete off: <input type="text" name="q4" id="script_4" autocomplete="off"><br>
</body>
```

This works, but when trying on another pages it sometimes won't:
e.g. http://spitsnieuws.nl/ and http://dumpert.nl work but http://nu.nl and http://armorgames.com don't work. EDIT: Both give

> Uncaught exception: TypeError:
>   '$("input[type='text']").autocomplete'
>   is not a function

Trying the autocomplete of jquery ui has more problems:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name           autocomplete
// @description    autocomplete
// @include        *
// ==/UserScript==

// Add jQuery
var GM_JQ = document.createElement('script');
GM_JQ.src = 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js';
GM_JQ.type = 'text/javascript';
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(GM_JQ);

var GM_CSS = document.createElement('link');
GM_CSS.rel = 'stylesheet';
GM_CSS.href = 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery-ui.css';
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(GM_CSS);

var GM_JQ_autocomplete = document.createElement('script');
GM_JQ_autocomplete.type = 'text/javascript';
GM_JQ_autocomplete.src = 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js';
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(GM_JQ_autocomplete);

// Check if jQuery's loaded
function GM_wait() 
{
    if(typeof window.jQuery == 'undefined') 
    { 
        window.setTimeout(GM_wait,100); 
    }
    else 
    { 
        $ = window.jQuery; 

        letsJQuery(); 
    }
}
GM_wait();

// All your GM code must be inside this function
function letsJQuery() 
{
    $("input[type='text']").each(function(index)
    {
        $(this).val("test autocomplete");
    });

    $("input[type='text']").autocomplete({
        source: function(request, response) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "http://mysite/jquery_autocomplete.php",
                dataType: "jsonp",
                success: function(data) {
                    response($.map(data, function(item) {
                        return {
                            label: item,
                            value: item
                        }
                    }))
                }
            })
        }
    });
}
```

This will work on my html page, http://spitsnieuws.nl and http://dumpert.nl but not on http://nu.nl and http://armorgames.com (idem as plugin)

However the error on nu and armorgames is now:

```
http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery-ui.css
Declaration syntax error

Line 18:
   100%; top: 0; left: 0; position: absolute; opacity: 0; filter:Alpha(Opacity=0);
  --------------------------------------------------------------------------------^
```

The input elements:

```
//http://spitsnieuws.nl
<input class="frmtxt ac_input" type="text" id="zktxt" name="query" autocomplete="off">
//http://dumpert.nl
<input type="text" name="srchtxt" id="srchtxt">
//http://nu.nl
<input id="zoekfield" name="q" type="text" value="Zoek nieuws" onfocus="this.select()" type="text">
//http://armorgames.com
<input type="text" name="search" value="" class="search">
```

Anyone know why the autocomplete functionality doesn't work? Why the request to the php page is not being made? And why I can't add my autocomplete to google.com?

Edit:
Added armorgames and error messages

### Answer

Well I found out that I also should check if autocomplete.js has loaded (instead of only jquery.js)

With the autocomplete of jQuery UI

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name           autocomplete
// @description    autocomplete
// @include        *
// ==/UserScript==

// Add jQuery

var GM_CSS = document.createElement('link');
GM_CSS.type = 'text/css';
GM_CSS.rel = 'stylesheet';
GM_CSS.href = 'http://mysite/jquery/development-bundle/themes/ui-lightness/jquery.ui.all.css';
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(GM_CSS);

function includeJS(jsPath) 
{ 
    var script = document.createElement("script"); 
    script.setAttribute("type", "text/javascript"); 
    script.setAttribute("src", jsPath); 
    document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script); 
}; 

includeJS("http://mysite/jquery/development-bundle/jquery-1.4.2.js");
includeJS("http://mysite/jquery/development-bundle/ui/jquery.ui.core.js");
includeJS("http://mysite/jquery/development-bundle/ui/jquery.ui.widget.js");
includeJS("http://mysite/jquery/development-bundle/ui/jquery.ui.position.js");

// Check if jQuery's loaded
function GM_wait() 
{
    if(typeof window.jQuery == 'undefined') 
    { 
        window.setTimeout(GM_wait,100); 
    }
    else 
    { 
        $ = window.jQuery; 

        letsJQuery(); 
    }
}
GM_wait();

// All your GM code must be inside this function
function letsJQuery() 
{
    $("input[type='text']").each(function(index)
    {
        $(this).val("test autocomplete");
    });

    //wait till script is loaded
    $.getScript("http://mysite/jquery/development-bundle/ui/jquery.ui.autocomplete.js", function(){
        //using remote data from other domain using JSONP
        $("input[type='text']").autocomplete({
            source: function(request, response) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "http://mysite/jquery_autocomplete.php",
                    dataType: "jsonp",
                    success: function(data) {
                        response($.map(data, function(item) {
                            return {
                                label: item,
                                value: item
                            }
                        }))
                    }
                })
            }
        }); 
    });
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the first example, you're waiting for jQuery to load and then firing off `letsJQuery`, which then calls `autocomplete`, but how do you know that autocomplete has finished loading?

Comment: Good question, I find the 'debugger' of Opera a bit limiting, so I'll try something else to check if the AutoComplete has loaded.

Comment: This is part of the solution I present where I load it in the ajax call, then activate it in the success: portion (and the reason I did it that way).  You COULD load the jQuery.js in the ajax, then chain using the other method I illustrated with myother.js for the autocomplete, placing them sequentially.

Comment: thanks for pointing in the right direction (indeed autocomplete was yet loaded), @mark for the tip of chaining

Answer (score 3):

If you load the autocomplete in a jquery ajax call, you could then add the autocomplete functionality within the success: of the ajax call

```
    function includeJS(jsPath) 
    { 
        var script = document.createElement("script"); 
        script.setAttribute("type", "text/javascript"); 
        script.setAttribute("src", jsPath); 
        document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script); 
    }; 


function setAutocomplete()
    { 
    $("input[type='text']").autocomplete("http://mysite/jquery_autocomplete.php", {         
            dataType: 'jsonp',         
            parse: function(data) {         
                var rows = new Array();         
                for(var i=0; i<data.length; i++){         
                    rows[i] = {          
                        data:data[i],          
                        value:data[i],          
                        result:data[i] };         
                }         
                return rows;         
            },         
            formatItem: function(row, position, length) {         
                return row;         
            }         
        });         
    };
    $.ajax({ 
          url: "http://dev.jquery.com/view/trunk/plugins/autocomplete/jquery.autocomplete.js", 
          dataType: 'script', 
          cache: true, 
          success:  function(){
                  setAutocomplete();
                  includeJS('js/myother.js'); //another example of loading one on demand
                }
    });
```

Comment: if you do the $.ajax isn't it neccesery to add it to the webpage? like the document.createElement('script'); and document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild?

Comment: Yes, but I made the assumption (perhaps in error) that these were all wraped in the jquery wrapper $(document).ready(function(){ // Your code here }); Other than that, just running that function "adds" it to the page DOM attached to that selector.

Comment: As for the javascript, it it my understanding that this reads like: "Load and execute the script" as the first example here: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/ thus it exists in the page.

Comment: Made the assumption that the autocomplete was included. Added an example to do another a different way as well. (within that function chain)

Comment: Just a note: I did not edit/change your autocomplete code but simply added it to the function I created so that remains as you had it.

Answer (score 0):

Just making sure..

Your not looking for the auto-complete that opera has built in correct? If you are unsure what I mean go to settings -> preferences -> forms tab

On this tab you can type in values which opera will auto suggest when you type into text input fields. Its a bit limiting(which might be why you are doing this) but gets the majority of the common stuff to auto-complete.

Comment: I knew about the form tab but it's indeed limiting. Any other browser has autocomplete functionality build in, only not Opera